# Application crashed with __GI__abort error from _Unwind_Resume

Tags: c++

Call stack:

[image]

[image]

Anyone encountered this issue,  why abort happpened in _Unwind_Resume?

Answer (score 0):

If a function declares noexcept, but an exception occurs inside, the program will simply abort